# A less clear-cut tag synonym example

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have doubts about the potential equivalence (or not) of [christianity](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) and [ecclesiastical-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecclesiastical-latin).

The descriptions are:

> Use this tag for all questions related to Christianity. Consider also using more specific tags like "vulgata" or "ecclesiastical-latin" ([christianity](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity))

> This tag is used for questions concerning the liturgical and codified language of the church from the end of antiquity until today ([ecclesiastical-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecclesiastical-latin))

- On one hand,

  1. there is also Greek —and other in-scope languages, for that matter— in Christianity, and
  2. the [vulgata](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulgata) example could be seen as suggesting that there are Latin texts that are Christian but not properly Ecclesiastical.
- On the other hand [*sed contra*, haha, get it?],

  1. most —though not all— Christianity questions also touch Latin,
  2. There is little if any Latin stuff that is ecclesiastical but non-christian (depending on definitions, perhaps, as in Ecclesiastical=Catholic and Latin Evangelical texts are out of the former? Or some Medieval, ecclesial, non-Christian religion I'm not aware of? Are there any relevant, extant Jewish Latin texts, for example?)
  3. Isn't the Vulgate "codified language of the church"?

Should these be one? Or should at least all [ecclesiastical-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecclesiastical-latin) Q's be also tagged [christianity](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) for the sake of searchability?

Answer (score 4):

They are different enough, and they should be kept as they are (your reasons in the comments)

Comment: @cmw wouldn't that count as EL being a subset of Ch? Or is there no way to handle such a relation?

Comment: Got it, wasn't aware of the sign. I think I might write up a separate answer, but I think this is still the correct answer on reflection (but also voted up the other one while I think more about what the best course of action might be).

Comment: I voted for this because a question about the pronunciation of ecclesiastical Latin is not about Christianity so I don't think either tag contains the other.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta right! I hadn't thought about that!

Answer (score 1):

[ecclesiastical-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecclesiastical-latin) is a subset of [christianity](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) (your reasons in the comments).

But what is supposed to be done in that case?

Comment: I think it would make more sense if you replace the subset sign with words, as many here aren't mathematicians (at least I don't think I'm the only one!).

Answer (score 0):

They are the same and should be made synonyms (your reasons in the comments)